# Workstation Service Crashes After NetBIOS & DNS Name Change

Tags: windows, dns, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, netbios

I'm still not sure how this happened, but I have the following condition on an instance of Windows Server 2008 R2 running on HyperV:

- I can't login as any domain user on this server

  - This is because the 'Netlogon' service isn't started
- The Workstation service is a dependency of Netlogon and the Workstation service fails with error "The Workstation service terminated with service-specific error This network connection does not exist.."

  - EventID 7024
  - Error 2250
- The Workstation service won't start in Safe Mode either

I attempted to login as local Administrator and was unable to, Windows stated bad password but I know it's correct. To fix this, I used chntpw boot CD. I know loading and reading the hive is best-effort, but chntpw said the Administrator account was locked.

After logging in as a local Administrator, I have the following conditions:

- Time is incorrect by ~4 minutes

  - I am unable to adjust this, even via cli, as the Windows Time service is stopped as it relies on the Workstation service
- The hostname is half-incorrect somehow

  - After reviewing the Event Log, I found that the servername changed, seemingly randomly, yesterday at 8:42 AM ET. Somehow the NetBIOS and DNS names were changed, but %computername% and the system properties showed the correct hostname.
  - After the rename event, all the MS SQL services stopped on the server

Troubleshooting:

- Ran Malwarebytes and Vipre AV against the server and no threats were found
- Manually reset all instances of [bad hostname] to [good hostname] in the registry (backed them up first, obv) to no avail.
- Removed the vNIC and added another one in case there was some corruption there; no change.

Does anyone have any input on how to change the NetBIOS and DNS names back to what they should be? All renaming options in system properties are greyed out because a dependency is stopped.

Comment: I ended up just reinstalling Win 2k8 R2 over the existing one. I'd still like to know the core issue.

Comment: This issue is in some way related to MS Cluster Services. The NetBIOS names get renamed to the cluster service name which seems to cause a conflict.